# are we able to clear mysql terminal (not just clear but totally clean)?

Tags: linux, macos, terminal, mysql

I know that there are command such as `\! clear`, `system clear`, using `ctrl + l` in terminal to clear the terminal.

But I realize by clear, it's just leaving a gap and all previous results are still at the top that when we scroll we would still see the results from previous commands.

What I am wondering is if there's a command to totally clean up the terminal that it's new like opening a new terminal that when I scroll up the terminal it'll be only showing results of the current action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use " \! reset" command .
In contrast to clear, or Ctrl+L, reset will actually completely re-initialise the terminal, instead of just clearing the screen. However, it won't re-instantiate the shell (bash). That means that bash's state is the same as before, just as if you were merely clearing the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tput reset`.

Besides `reset` and `tput reset` you can use following shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -e \\033c
```

This sends control characters Esc-C to the console which resets the terminal.

```
Google Keywords: Linux Console Control Sequences
```

man console_codes says:

> The sequence ESC c causes a terminal reset, which is what you want if
>   the screen is all garbled. The oft-advised "echo ^V^O" will only make
>   G0 current, but there is no guarantee that G0 points at table a). In
>   some distributions there is a program reset(1) that just does "echo
>   ^[c". If your terminfo entry for the console is correct (and has an
>   entry rs1=\Ec), then "tput reset" will also work.

reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26975/how-to-clear-terminal-completely